# Loading a file from the browser, without a web server

Tags: javascript, http, browser, hyperlink, xmlhttprequest

So I need to load a file from disk somehow, and access its contents.. Sort of like how

```
<link rel="stylesheet">
```

works. Is there a way to do this? XHR requires a web server.. and using something like the above doesn't let me access the contents of the file..

Comment: Where is your Javascript running?

Comment: What do you mean by load and access? And where is the "disk" in question located?

Comment: all the files are in the same folder, on a hard drive.

The javascript is running in the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your page is also on the local disk, you should be able to use XHR with a `file://` URL.

Comment: oh interesting, I didn't know that. So I guess I should check the url of the current file, to see if it's being loaded from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean loading from a CD or the HDD? You'll need the full address that it is stored at, for example, something on the desktop would be:

"file:///c:/documents%20and%20settings/user/desktop/file.css"

%20 means a space.